# Excel adds extra quotes on CSV export

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I've recently created an application which adds items to a Database by CSV. After adding items I realized that lots of my values had extra quotes (") that weren't needed and this was messing up my ordering.

The problem is that when exporting to a CSV from Excel, Excel adds extra quotes to all of my values that already have a quote in them. I've shown the difference below:

Original Item: **Drill Electric Reversible 1/2" 6.3A**

Exported Item: *"Drill Electric Reversible 1/2"" 6.3"*

**Note: the CSV export is adding three (3) extra quotes ("). Two on the ends, and one after the original intended quote.**

Is there a setting I can change, or a formatting property I can set on the Excel File/Column? Or do I have to live with it and remove these quotes in my back-end code before adding them to the Database?

Comment: The surrounding quotes are standard for a CSV, so I wouldn't worry about them. Just make sure your importer is accounting for enclosing quotes.   The inside quote is Excel's way of escaping the double quotes. A bit annoying, I'll grant you but it's part of the standard.

Comment: *`The problem is that when exporting to a CSV from Excel, Excel adds extra quotes to all of my values that already have a quote in them`* - without trying to import it, how do you know that this is a **problem**?

Comment: python3 with `csv.reader` is able to handle the extra double quotes well while plain `open` can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is entirely normal.  The outer quotes are added because this is a string.  The inner quote is doubled to escape it.  Same kind of thing you'd see in a SQL query for example.  Use the TextFieldParser class to have tried and true framework code care of the parsing of this for you automatically.

Answer (score 4):

That's standard.

The values within a CSV file should have quotes around them (otherwise commas and linebreaks inside a field may be misinterpreted).

The way to escape a quote within a field is to double it, just as you are seeing.

I suggest you read about the [basic rules of CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules):

> CSV is a delimited data format that has fields/columns separated by the comma character and records/rows terminated by newlines. **Fields that contain a special character (comma, newline, or double quote), must be enclosed in double quotes.** If a line contains a single entry which is the empty string, it may be enclosed in double quotes. **If a field's value contains a double quote character it is escaped by placing another double quote character next to it.** The CSV file format does not require a specific character encoding, byte order, or line terminator format.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Hmm. This only happens in fields which already contain a quote. So if I do a replace " with "" in my code behind it should fix the problem? or would I have to replace the " with a """? EDIT: Wait, I'd have to replace it in the Excel file.

Comment: @Lando - use a CSV parsing library and make your life easy.

Comment: @Oded Any idea why Excel not double quoting single quote?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the Unicode Character "DOUBLE PRIME"

```
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2033/index.htm
```

in your Excel data. To export from Excel into a UTF-8 or UTF-16 .csv you'll have to provide a schema.ini with an appropriate CharacterSet property. Obviously, the tool you use to import the .csv into your database has to be Unicode aware too.

Depending on the DBMS a more direct way of data transfer (SELECT/INSERT ... INTO ... IN ) can be used, thereby eliminating the .csv entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting from Excel as TAB delimited files. I find it easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all characters Right Double Quotation Mark by characters Left Double Quotation Mark. They look similar, Excel will be confused and let the text unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will only help if your end output is HTML. This is the javascript solution so obviously you'll need to redo this in C# or whichever language you're working in:

```
base = base.replace(/""/gi, '&quot;');
base = base.replace(/'/gi, '&#39;');
```

Apply this before you parse the CSV.