# why excel export csv doesn't quote single quote?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, mysql-workbench

When I export the data from excel as a CSV format it encapsulates some data in double quotes. 
E.g.

1. `8"` becomes `"8"""`. And I believe this operation is trying to get the database to understand the inside quote later on.
2. but for single quote `8'`, it keeps the same and this causes problem(see the pic below) while I am importing the csv.

Why not quoting the `8'` into `"8'"` too?

**`8'` becomes `'` while importing, while `"8'"` will result in `8'` And not quoting single quote leads some data loss.**
[image]

question related:
[what does quotechar mean in mysql while importing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472683/what-does-quotechar-mean-in-mysql-while-importing-data/50473102#50473102)

[Excel adds extra quotes on CSV export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200056/excel-adds-extra-quotes-on-csv-export)

Comment: @BobKaufman Come on man. Didn't you see that `8'` becomes only `'` while importing? I feel sorry if the pic is not good.

Comment: question is pretty clear. it should not be closed.

Comment: @RavinderReddy thank you for supporting.

Comment: @Rick... Excel just does its thing and its thing is to murder data. First rule: keep your data out of excel if you care about its integrity ;) Secondly, I think this might be a limitation of the mysql client you are using. If you hit the command line [you'll see that the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) allows you to specify `FIELDS [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']` That optional `OPTIONALLY` keyword is what you need. I don't see a checkbox in your screenshot of your client that suggests that it can handle the `OPTIONALLY` option.

Comment: OPTIONALLY (I'm liking this word) consider outputting that `xls` to `csv` where you output EVERY field with double quotes rendering the optional  `OPTIONALLY` keyword superfluous so you can use your mysql client. [See here for some options](https://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I'm a big fan of VBA for jobs like this, but I can definitely say that I've used Libreoffice in the past to pop open an xls file to gain more control over exports of the data.

Comment: @JNevill there's an button and I knew it and tried it. see https://imgur.com/XRG3s5S. But whatever value I change the enclosing character value, it just pops out an absolutely unknown error window so I've been avoiding changing that. And btw, I also have some data quoted in double quotes (`8"` gets converted into `"8"""` by Excel can be recognized correctly) so I think I can't change that. I would like to read and try your "options" now.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests you have a semi-colon delimited file with pipe encapsulation and that it's UTF-8 with a LF line seperator (Definitely not outputted from excel then... that sounds like a UNIX text file). So your data would look like: `|First field|;|Second field 'here'|;|"third field in quotes for some reason"|;|FourthField|` If it looks like that (of course yours is just one field: `|8'|`) then I can't imagine why would you would be erroring. What does the "log" say about that totally unhelpful error?

Comment: If, instead, you are truly using Excel's File>>Save and choosing the CSV option then you are getting a comma delimited, optionally double quote encapsulated file in ANSI (not UTF-8) with CRLF line endings (normal Windows line endings) and you'll have to adjust the form in Workbench for that.

Comment: Isn't ETL fun? Aren't flat files grand?</sarcasm>

Comment: @JNevill no no no. I am just doing a demostration about changing that enclosing value would cause unknown error. My datas are all placed in 1 column, 1 value each row. So field seperator is not important here I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing so many experiments, I finally found a pretty close answer.

Conclusion first:

- It is Mysql Workbench's problem. Its import wizard works badly. I test under Navicat for every test data, and Navicat get all things right.
- Single quote can caused unexpected behavior.

---

Test:

By default, Mysql workbench import wizard takes the first row value as column name, while in Navicat, I can configure that.

(All tests files are excel-exported csv utf8 encoding.)

test1:

e.g.: `8'`（only 1 record）, without column name.
 [image]
 Mysql: Pop out some unknown error and whatever configuration you change, can't get the original data.
 Navicat:works fine.

[image]
[image]

test2:

e.g.: `8'` , only 1 record with column name or have extra records without column name
 Mysql: Can handle single quote properly.
 Navicat: No problem.
[image]
[image]

test3:

If single quote exists, **for most situation** import wizard can't handle double quotes well.

e.g.: Single quote data comes before double quotes data.
[image]
  Mysql: Fails totally.
  Navicat: No problem.

[image]
[image]